# Correspondence between continuous maps and convergent sequences

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to find a topological space $X$ such that there is a bijection between $C(X,Y)$ and $\{convergent$ $sequences$ $in$ $Y\}$ for any Hausdorff space $Y$. The natural idea is to choose $X=\mathbb N$, but then I cannot find a suitable topology. I tried the co-finite topology since it feels like convergent sequence, but with it, any continuous map from $X \to Y$ would be a sequence fluctuating in $Y$ instead of a convergent sequence. Any help would be appreciated. Looking for a explicit construction.

Comment: What do you mean by "fluctuating"?

Comment: if I take co-finite topology, then for any open set in Y, the pre-image is a complement of finite set in $\mathbb N$, which implies there exists a $N$ such that the $N-tail$ would be in the open set. Then the tail would be in any open set in $Y$ @user10354138

Comment: You can't swap quantifiers like that!

Comment: @user10354138 for any open set, there would be a $N>0$ such that the $N-tail$ is in the open set? is the argument flawed?

Comment: If $f\colon(\mathbb{N},\text{cofinite})\to Y$ is continuous, then for any open $V\subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}V$ contains a tail $\{n\geq N\}$.  That doesn't say $\{n\geq N\}$ is contained in every $f^{-1}W$ whenever $W$ is open which is what you seems to be asserting.

Comment: @user10354138 sorry for the confusion. I mean for any open $V$, $f^{-1}V$ contains a tail, which is what I mean "fluctuating", and I think such a sequence would not be convergent.

Comment: @user10354138 I do not think the usual topologies like standard topology, lower-limit topology, co-finite topology and co-countable topology would work here together with $mathbb N$. Any suggestion?

Comment: Continuous maps from $\mathbb{N}$ with cofinite topology doesn't work because it excludes a lot of sequences such as a sequence where $x_0\neq x_1$ and $x_n=x_1$ for $n>1$. This function from $\mathbb{N}$ with cofinite topology is not continuous. Because a neighborhood around $x_0$ that does not contain $x_1$ has a finite preimage, and is therefore not open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of a convergent sequence is the following. $(x_n)_n$ converges to $x$ iff for each open $U$ around $x$ there exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N: x_n\in U$. This is the same as saying that the preimage of $U$ is cofinite. But to talk about neighborhoods of the limit $x$ it would be convenient if the limit was also a part of the map in $X\to Y$.

This motivates the bijection between convergent sequences in $Y$ and $C(\mathbb{N}\cup \{\infty\}, Y)$ where the topology on $\mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ is generated by $\{\{n\}| n\in \mathbb{N}\} \cup \{[n, \infty)\cup\{\infty\}| n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. The important part is that each point in $\mathbb{N}$ is isolated and that each neighborhood of $\infty$ is cofinite.

The bijection sends each convergent sequence to the function $$f:X\to Y: \begin{cases}n\mapsto x_n\\\infty\mapsto \lim_{n\to\infty}x_n\end{cases}$$
The continuity of the function $f$ follows from the initial observation that the preimage of any open $U$ containing the limit is cofinite.*

This bijection is injective, because limits are unique in Hausdorff spaces. And it is also surjective since every continuous function $X\to Y$ gives rise to a convergent sequence by considering the image of $\mathbb{N}\subset X$.

***EDIT:**
To explain the continuity of $f$ in more detail, the argument is as follows.
For $f$ to be continuous we need the preimage of any open to be open. So consider any open $V\subset Y$. We split the argument into two cases. Either $V$ contains the limit or $V$ doesn't contain the limit.

**Case 1:**
$V$ contains the limit, this implies the preimage of $V$ is a cofinite set and the point $\infty$. By definition this set is open.

**Case 2:**
$V$ does not contain the limit, in this case the preimage of $V$ is a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ because $X$ has the discrete topology on $\mathbb{N}$ all subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are open, therefore the preimage of $V$ is open.

This proves that the preimage of any open in $Y$ is open in $X$.

Comment: The expression for the generating set is not a well formed formula, nor set builder notation, . nor coherent.

Comment: It should now be fixed.

Comment: @jMdA nice answer. I guess we can directly use the topology $\{\emptyset\}\cup\{[n,\infty]\cap \mathbb N: n\in \mathbb N\}$

Comment: @xyz you also want all subsets of $\Bbb N$ to be open..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma why? I think $\{\emptyset\}\cup\{[n,\infty]\cap \mathbb N : n\in \mathbb N \}$ would be enough? as $(y_n)_{n=1}^{n=\infty}$ is continuous iff $\forall$ open neighbourhood of $y_\infty, y^{-1}(O)=[n,\infty]$, which is equivalent to the convergence of $(y_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to $y_\infty$?

Comment: @xyz You want to be able to arbitarily define the values on $\Bbb N$ and that is the easiest way to ensure continuity. Moreover, the space becomes compact Hausdorff so has better theory in $C(X)$ theory.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma oh! I guess I see it. My argument is flawed, since $\forall$ open neighbourhood of $y_\infty, y^{-1}(O)=[n,\infty]$ is not equivalent to the convergence of $y_n$ but strictly stronger. I need to take the topology generated by $\{S\cup[n,\infty]: S\subset \mathbb N, n\in \mathbb N\}$. then $\forall$ open neighbourhood of $y_\infty, y^{-1}(O)=S \cup [n,\infty]\}$ for some $S\subset \mathbb N$, which is equivalent to the convergence.

Comment: @xyz Does that topology contain open sets that don't contain $\infty$? Because every finite set needs to be open.

Comment: @jMdA all open sets in the above topology contains $\infty$. Why ever finite set needs to be open?

Comment: @xyz Because you need sequences like $(x_0, x_1, x_1, x_1, \cdots) \to x_1$ to be continuous.  And the preimage of an open set containing $x_0$ but not $x_1$ is exactly the singleton $\{0\}$. Similar arguments show that every singleton has to be open, and therefore every set in $\mathbb{N}$ needs to be open.

Comment: But in the above topology, I only need to consider the open neighbourhood of the limit? since $f^{-1}(O)=S\cup[n,\infty]$ and $O$ must contain $x_\infty$

Comment: No, the entire function needs to be continuous. It doesn't just need to be continuous at $\infty$. I excluded consideration of any open that doesn't contain the limit because its preimage is trivially open, since every subset of $\mathbb{N}$ is open by definition. The argument simply doesn't work if this is not the case.

Comment: @jMdA thank you! I see it.